# How to choose the correct soda keg "type" replacement posts?

Tags: keg, corny-keg

New to kegging, got myself a used ball lock Firestone/Pepsi soda keg. But when I've been cleaning and sanitizing the posts when I got it/after use, they seemed SUPER beat up. There is a washer (maybe? some sort of plastic nub) inside that is all cracked up, same with the o-rings, the gas dip tube is plastic and looks pretty beat up. And I haven't even looked at the poppets yet.

I'm considering just buying replacement post assemblies, but I've found three different "types":

- Type A fits Firestone V, VI, Challenger and Super Challenger kegs
- Type B fits Cornelius Spartan, Super Champion and 'R' kegs
- Type C fits John Wood 85 and older Firestone Challenger kegs

Then there is [this kit](http://www.northernbrewer.com/pin-lock-to-ball-lock-conversion-post-kit) I found that seems to want to sell me the both posts without any concern to type.

The question ends up being, is there functional difference between replacing the post assemblies between types other than profile? Must I choose the right one or will any work?

And if I must choose the correct one, how do I determine my kegs model [when it doesn't seem to be labeled where I purchased it](http://www.kegerator.com/reconditioned-homebrew-ball-lock-keg-conversion-kit-stainless-steel/CK1-CL1-KIT.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locks usually only need replaced if coverting between pinlock to ball lock, unless it's really deformed where the oring can't seal or the lock doesn't attach good.

I would start with just a universal corney rebuild kit, it has 5 orings in it (lid x1, post x2, lock x2)

Then address the poppets if they leak, as these are the part that have a couple of variants.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do that. Are you familiar with the plastic insert within the post? That is in really rough shape. In searching I've found replacements parts that sort of look like it, but I'm not sure. From what I can tell, I think it might be what is know as a "John Wood Ball Lock." Sort of looks [like this](http://cdn3.volusion.com/vgguw.gfckt/v/vspfiles/photos/KG87023-1.jpg).

Comment: @nevets138 I've seen the plastic tubes on the gas / in lock. But the other tube (pick up / out) should be long and stainless. These parts are universal, your corney oring set has the seals for them, even in a beat up condition they should seal unless the lip is really messed up or broken.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I'm not referring to the gas tube that goes into the keg, this is actually a hard small piece of plastic that is inserted up into the post. Looks like this: http://cdn3.volusion.com/vgguw.gfckt/v/vspfiles/photos/KG87645-4.jpg?1444700842

Comment: @nevets138 hmm I honestly haven't seen that style, it appears to be a self sealing part. All I've seen are the same as the dip tube, just shorter made of stainless or plastic but use an oring to seal.

Comment: Coming in late on this one but I've got an old 10gal keg that I'm trying to get working and am having some issues getting it to seal. I got some of those nylon washers from William's Brewing. 
https://www.williamsbrewing.com/FIRESTONE-NYLON-INSERT-P101.aspx
Mine were not as tall but they seem to mostly fit. I've also found some parts here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxdWw_AKJdXzNmRjTWFnSDNTOTA/view on page 14